# How to edit textarea value using another textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have one Textarea box having its value "some initial content" 
I want to edit its value using another Textarea box

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.myParagraphContent = "Some{{SecondTextareaContent}} initial content.";
});
```

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<p>{{myParagraphContent}}</p>

<textarea ng-model="SecondTextareaContent"></textarea>
<textarea ng-model="myParagraphContent"></textarea>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Update

You can use ngChange instead. Check the demo [here](https://jsbin.com/jupeminaxa/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

For the Javascript part:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
     $scope.SecondTextareaContent = '';
     $scope.myParagraphContent = 'Some initial content.';
     $scope.onChange = function() {
        $scope.myParagraphContent = 'Some ' + $scope.SecondTextareaContent + ' initial content.';
     };
});
```

For the HTML part:

```
<textarea ng-model="SecondTextareaContent" ng-change="onChange()"></textarea>
<textarea ng-model="myParagraphContent"></textarea>
```

---

### Old Answer

For the Javascript part:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
     $scope.SecondTextareaContent = '';
     $scope.myParagraphContent = 'Some initial content.';
     $scope.onKeyDown = function() {
        $scope.myParagraphContent = 'Some ' + $scope.SecondTextareaContent + ' initial content.';
     };
});
```

For the HTML part:

```
<textarea ng-model="SecondTextareaContent" ng-keydown="onKeyDown()"></textarea>
<textarea ng-model="myParagraphContent"></textarea>
```

Comment: not working, when i type in SecondTextareaContent its showing like that is parragraph:   Some ${$scope.SecondTextareaContent} initial content.

Comment: Removed the template literal. Try it now

Comment: when I type 'demo' it only shows 'dem' last character is missing

Comment: when type only one character not getting any value in myParagraphContent

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this;

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<p>{{myParagraphContent}}</p>

<textarea ng-model="SecondTextareaContent" ng-change='myParagraphContent=SecondTextareaContent'></textarea>
<textarea ng-model="myParagraphContent"  ></textarea>

</div>
```

also if you want in the ng-change you can use some function to execute.

Answer (score -1):

I tried to understand you. something like that ?

```js
const txt = document.querySelectorAll(".txt");
const setValue = () => {
  txt[1].value = txt[0].value;
}
txt[0].addEventListener("input", setValue, false);
```

```html
<textarea class="txt"></textarea>
<textarea class="txt"></textarea>
```